# Can Google Data Studio do time-series graphs at the hour level?

Tags: time-series, looker-studio

Every example of a time-series graph I've seen for Google Data Studio has a metric plotted per day. Is there any way to configure the granularity of the time axis (hour, month, etc)?

I want to show the count of events per hour throughout one day. 
My columns are in bigquery as types datetime:TIMESTAMP and count:INTEGER

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now, there seems to be a straightforward way:

0. Assuming that you have a Time Series plot, use Timestamp for your dimension and want to show hourly aggregated values.
1. Select the dimension's preferences:

[image: Edit the timestamp dimension]

2. Change `Type` to `Date Hour`

[image: Select Date Hour type]

Answer (score 7):

This is old, but its high in search results, and I found the correct answer here: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Data-Studio/Is-it-possible-to-aggregate-by-hour/td-p/1104815

Click the pencil next to the datasource, on your timestamp, click on the type column, and change "Date(YYYYMMDD" to another format, such as DATE HOUR("YYYYMMDDHH") to get hourly aggregation on the graphs.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot, which pencil should I click?

Comment: Does this still work or is that a legacy function? I wanted to change to a minute-based time series, but the graph still shows daily, even if I refresh the data. How can I show the graph aggregated by minute?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Based on new updates to Data Studio, @Brian's answer above is the correct one.

You can create a calculated field with the [TODATE funciton](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300). Example formula can be `TODATE(source_field, 'SECONDS', '%Y%m%d%H')`. Then this field should be marked as `Date(YYYYMMDDHH)` in the field editing screen.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this. If the data is broken up hour by hour, make the hour column(s) the Time Dimension. If all of the hour data isn't in a single column, you may want to reformat your data (manually or using a data prep source, your choice). Or you can go into the time setting of the field and change it into hours.